# How can i use javascript for 5 star rating

Tags: javascript, html

am trying to get the 5 star rating using the html5 and css.

What i have done is, i have taken 2 images one is red and green color stars.

inititally the star will be red, when we click the stars to rating, 
the till the clicked star it should get green.

so i used onclick change image...

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeImage()
{
element=document.getElementById('myimage')
if (element.src.match("bulbon"))
  {
  element.src="images/1.png";
  }
else
  {
  element.src="images/2.png";
  }
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()"src="images/1.png">
<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()"src="images/1.png">
<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()"src="images/1.png">
<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()"src="images/1.png">
<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()"src="images/1.png">



</body>
</html>
```

what i need now is, when i click the stars for rating, only the first star is getting changed. instead till the star i clicked should get color changed...

how can i do this???

Comment: you are using the same ID for all your images - ID is a unique attribute and cannot be used in such manner, use classes instead

Comment: Since this has nothing whatsoever to do with canvas, please remove the canvas tag. You also aren't using jquery, though you could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly use jQuery to hook up your events, using `on` attributes is very outdated. Secondly, you have duplicated `id` attributes, which is invalid. Finally, you can use `prevAll()` to get all the preceding elements and update them. Try this:

```
<div class="rating-container">
    <img class="star" src="images/1.png">
    <img class="star" src="images/1.png">
    <img class="star" src="images/1.png">
    <img class="star" src="images/1.png">
    <img class="star" src="images/1.png">
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.rating-container .star').click(function() {
        $('.rating-container .star').prop('src', 'images/1.png');
        $(this).prevAll('.star').addBack().prop('src', 'images/2.png');
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RCw3H/)

Note the example is changing the `class` of some `div` elements as I don't have access to your images, but the logic is the same.

Comment: Which version of jquery library you have used?

Comment: @Pandora 1.9, although any back to 1.7 should be fine. If you're using < 1.7 change `prop` to `attr`.

Comment: @BillyChan `on` event attributes were originally part of HTML 4. They are very clunky to use, and are an incredibly poor separation of concerns. They are not deprecated (mostly due to HTML5 doing its best to not break legacy code) however they should be IMO.

Comment: I modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/RCw3H/2/) to a delegated event handler. Should be slightly more efficient. +1 though. Great solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

my last approach was to use a "star mask" png image where the stars are transparent, and behind that container theres a div animating to the percentual representation of the points,
i likethe effect und you have very precise amount

```
function updateStars() {//Animatestars in Searchresult
    $('.stars').each(function (i){ 
        var el = $(this).find('.countSpan').text();
        var amount = (parseFloat(el) * 2)  * 10 ;
        $('.Newstar_bar').eq(i).animate({'width': amount+'%'},1000,'easeOutQuint');
                console.log('updatedStars with amount : '+amount);
    });   
}
```

html :

```
<div class="stars" >
  <div class="Newstar_container" style="top:-5px;">
   <div class="Newstar_background"></div>
   <div class="Newstar_bar"></div>
   <div class="Newstar_wrap"></div>
 </div>
<span class="countSpan" style="display:none">2.3</span>
</div>
```